# How can I access a div through javascript on a different page in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where I need to use Jquery to refresh a div. However, the div is not on the same page that is calling for the refresh.

```
$("#comment_partial_2").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'bedsheet_lines/comment_display_partial', locals: { id: 3081 } ).html_safe %>");
```

How can I specify the Url/page/?? so that the `#comment_partial_2` reflects the page where the div is such as `$("/slitter_bedsheets/2030/#comment_partial_2")`?

The refresh works fine as long as I call it from the page where the div is. However, I'm using a popup form to change a field and if I call the JS from there, it isn't pointing to the correct page for the refresh.

Comment: Are the popup contents in an iframe?

Comment: @BradWerth No, the pop up is from a link_to called with ` 'data-popup' => true, :remote => true,`